# How to alter a property of a component in Angular whenever there is a change in the backend DB (without manual refresh)

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have corresponding method to set the value of property **status** for which I'm subscribing to the store to obtain the value. But in my case, I want this property status to be automatically updated whenever there is a change in my backend DB (status change in DB basically). How can I make this happen without manually refreshing the page ?
Pic:  [The icon in the first column as shown needs to be changed to a different one (which the getLegend() method does for me) whenever there is a change in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOPm0.png)

HTML:

```
 <data-table-column [property]="'status'">
    <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item" let-column="column" let-row="row">
      <div>
        <img alt="icon" class="legendIcon" src="{{ getLegend(item[column.property]) }}" />
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </data-table-column>
```

My effects call:

```
 loadMyList$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(homeActions.loadInit),
  switchMap(() =>
    this.homeService.getMyList().pipe(
      map((data: any) =>
        homeActions.loadListSuccess({
          payload: data
        })
      ),
      catchError(error => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
          return of(homeActions.loadListSuccess({ payload: { records: [] } }));
        }
        return of(homeActions.loadListFailure({ error: error }));
      })
    )
  )
)
);
```

My **service call** looks like this:

```
getMyList(): Observable<any> {
const url = this.constructGlobalUrl('/api/v1/listdata');
const options = {
  params: new HttpParams().append('canShowSpinner', 'true')
};
return this.http.get<any>(url, options);
```

}

Please comment if you are in need of anything else !

Comment: Look into [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) and [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

Comment: nope nothing with websockets and stuff, need to add something in store. Need to know exactly what's that. Something like an observable or something which keeps listening to any changes in DB

Comment: If you can not use Websockets than I guess your alternative is polling the Shop at regular intervals

Comment: you must **manually** say Angular that some change. An observable is NOT a big-brother of your database. Each time you make a change, say it to Angular, or you can use a timer to check if some has changed in your database each a number of milliseconds